# Can I undefine EXIT_SUCCESS?

Tags: eclipse, enums, mingw, c-preprocessor

I'd like to define my own Enumerated type: ExitType.  I wrote it like so:

```
enum ExitType{
  EXIT_SUCCESS,
  EXIT_FAILURE,
  EXIT_OTHERTYPE
  };
```

I have a function that returns an ExitType.  On some conditions it returns EXIT_SUCCESS.  But I get the error message that you can't cast from an int to an ExitType.  Can I undefine EXIT_SUCCESS for my IDE, or am I stuck using `static_cast<int>(EXIT_SUCCESS)`?  It seems to introduce the possibility that their EXIT_SUCCESS will line up with my EXIT_OTHERTYPE, etc.

I'm using Eclipse Helios with the CDT, MinGW32 and SDL.  All 32-bit, and the latest versions.

**Edit**: Tried undefining EXIT_SUCCESS with the preprocessor.

```
#undef EXIT_SUCCESS
#undef EXIT_FAILURE

enum ExitType{
    EXIT_SUCCESS,
    EXIT_FAILURE,
    EXIT_OTHERTYPE,
    EXIT_NOEXIT
};
```

Result:
..\src\EventManager.cpp:12:7: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'ExitType'

**Edit 2**: When I moved my undefines AFTER the inclusion of <SDL/SDL.h>, the error went away.  A GREP of the SDL code doesn't turn up anything matching EXIT_SUCCESS, though.

Comment: EXIT_SUCCESS is defined in stdlib.h. That doesn't seem to be your problem though. Your error says you can't implicitly cast from into to ExitType (which is correct, that conversion requires an explicit cast). The conversion from ExitType to int can be done implicitly.

Comment: Note that you won't be able to get other people to use your code if they cannot use `<stdlib.h>` with your header because of the conflict with `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`.  That may or may not matter to you in the short term, but don't make a habit of it.  Or, IOW, it is a bad idea to redefine standard names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#undef EXIT_SUCCESS` should undefine the preprocessor symbol `EXIT_SUCCESS`, which is what I assume is going on here. But only do that if you're CERTAIN that you will not break anything by doing so!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  We'll see if anything appears broken as I continue working on the project.

Comment: In general, nothing may appear to break... because EXIT_SUCCESS, as a preprocessor symbol, is most likely defined to be the int "0"... and enums can decay to ints... and your EXIT_SUCCESS is the first value in your enum... which mean that its integral value is 0... which means that nothing will really change at all!

You can avoid this in the future by wrapping your enums in a namespace, assuming you're programming in C++